# Laravel 5.5: How to Keeping Laravel User session alive after system is idle

Tags: php, laravel-5

My System every after sometime of being idle returns the error below when i refresh it.

Image here:
[Laravel Error Displayed after a given time of inactivity of a system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ3l6.png)

I changed session lifetime from 120 to 120000000000 in the **session.php** file as shown below but seems not to work

```
<?php

return [
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
 'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120000000000),
 'expire_on_close' => false,

'encrypt' => false,
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
 'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'store' => null,
'lottery' => [2, 100],
 'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
  ),

'path' => '/',
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
'http_only' => true,
'same_site' => null,

];
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the value in the .env file:

> SESSION_LIFETIME=525600

that is in the root of the project because it takes this default value, and after doing this you can apply the commands: `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` to take the new changes.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use laravel built-in functionality (Remember me). You may pass a boolean value as the second argument to the attempt method, which will keep the user authenticated or you can manually logout. You can find this method inside `LoginController` which will be in a `AuthenticatesUsers` Trait. Also Your users table must include the string remember_token column, which will be used to store the "remember me" token. In latest versions of laravel these things are included by default.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
   // The user is being remembered...
}
```

> The alternative would be to set `SESSION_LIFETIME=120` in your `.env` file. I would recommend to set few years like maybe 68 years which is equal to `35791394` minutes. So set it like `SESSION_LIFETIME=35791394`. After setting session time you need to run these commands.

1. php artisan config:cache or php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan cache:clear